# How do I exclude "0" values from a standard deviation calculation in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, finance, standard-deviation

I am trying to exclude all zero values from my standard deviation calculations. For instance, if my data range has three numbers: 0,1,2 then I only want to calculate the standard deviation of 1 and 2.

Here is my current code (for reference- the top portion of my code is being used to reference certain cell names, that way the ensuing data is properly pulled):

```
Sub DownsideSTDVCalc()

    Dim fund As String
    Dim checkFund
    Dim item As String
    fund = Worksheets(12).Range("A2").Value
     
    For i = 2 To 48
        checkFund = Worksheets(11).Columns(i)
        item = Worksheets(11).Columns(i).Cells(1, 1)
        If item = fund Then
            Dim values
            Dim qtd
            values = Worksheets(11).Range(Worksheets(11).Cells(2, i), Worksheets(11).Cells(4, i))
            For j = 1 To UBound(values) - LBound(values)
                values(j, 1) = values(j, 1)
            Next
            qtd = Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev_S(values)

            Worksheets(12).Range("b2").Value = qtd
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: VBA doesn't have any fancy array manipulation that would let you add or remove elements based on value. You'll have to construct a second array with just the non-zero values.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1207274/stdev-p-ignore-cells-with-value-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Debug.Print StdDevNoZero(Selection)
End Sub


Function StdDevNoZero(rng As Range)
    Dim f, addr
    addr = rng.Address(False, False)
    f = "STDEV.S(IF(" & addr & ">0," & addr & "))"
    StdDevNoZero = rng.Parent.Evaluate(f)
End Function
```